# Word for objects satisfying a formula

Tags: logic, soft-question, terminology

Is there a word in logic for the class of individuals satisfying a given formula $\varphi$ ? I am also looking for a word for the individual obtained by interpreting the singular term $\iota v \varphi$ (provided it exists)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by $\iota v \varphi$

Comment: The official word for individuals 'fulfilling' a property is 'satisfy'. ... but I am not sure if there is a word for the class of objects that satisfy a formula.

Comment: The iota symbol in the question refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description , that is, if $f(x) = \{x\}$, then $\iota ~ f(x) = x$.  It dereferences a singleton.  A term that satisfies a formula is usually called a "witness".

Comment: @DanielV, I don't understand your explanation. See Mauro ALLEGRANZA's answer below for what I mean by $\iota v \varphi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For : $\iota v \varphi(v)$ see [Definite description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_description#Mathematical_logic) :

> it means "the *unique* object $v$ such that $\varphi(v)$".

For the class defined by the *property* $\varphi(x)$, i.e. $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$, sometimes I've read [truth-set](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truth%20set).

In traditional logic the [extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_(semantics)) of a *concept* consists of the things to which it applies.

Comment: You have basically answered my question, but I'll leave it open for a while to see whether there are any more elegant expressions.